# React: How to wait data before using "this.state.x" into a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous

I'm currently learning React, and some stuff are not so easy for a newbie...

I have a simple component which `renders` this (note that it renders a `li` array thanks to **function `getSlots`**):

```
render () {
    return (
        <ul>
          {this.getSlots(this.state.viewing).map(item => <li key={item}>{item}</li>)}
        </ul>
    )
  }
```

Function `getSlots` is:

```
constructor (props) {...}

getSlots (viewing) {

    SOME STUFF...

    const monday = this.state.house.monday

    return SOME STUFF...
  }

componentDidMount () {...}

render () {...}
```

The point is that `getSlots` needs data to be fetched in `componendDidMount` to work. Indeed, at this time, `getSlots` doesn't work (it crashes) because it runs before data are fetched (`this.state.house.monday` is "empty" when it runs).

How do I wait for data to be fetched before running `getSlots`? Thanks for your clue.

Comment: Just return an empty array while `this.state.house` is not what you expect.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're going to need to conditionally render. Provide a loading state to be loaded prior to asynchronously required data. You'll want something like the following:

```
class WrapperComponent extends PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
            isLoaded: false,
            data: null
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        MyApiCall.then(
            res => this.setState({
                // using spread operator, you will need transform-object-rest-spread from babel or
                // another transpiler to use this
                ...this.state, // spreading in state for future proofing
                isLoaded: true,
                data: res.data
            })
        );
    }

    render() {
        const { isLoaded, data } = this.state;
        return (
            {
                isLoaded ?
                    <PresentaionComponentThatRequiresAsyncData data={ data } /> :
                    <LoadingSpinner /> // or whatever loading state you want, could be null
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: It works like a charm. Solution by @Maxim Saenko also works. One more question linked to this one but using `react router`. I have a route like this one `<Route path='/schedule' render={() => (<Schedule {...this.state} otherData='just a test' />)} />`. As you see, I pass my `state` and some `otherData`. I succeed in `Schedule` component to retrieve `otherData`with `this.props.otherData`. I can also retrieve some `stuff` from my `state` but not the ones which need first to be fetched from DB. How do I wait for these data again?

Comment: Anytime you have asynchronously loaded data, you will need to provided a pre-loaded state, and an after loaded state. Conditional rendering is your friend! If you need more explicit instructions, let me know.

Comment: I think I get it, it works. In my route: `<Route path='/schedule' render={() => (<Schedule {...this.state} />)} />` and in my `Schedule` component the conditional rendering as you explain:  `{this.props.areSlotsReady && this.getSlots(this.props.viewing).map(item => <li key={item}>{item}</li>)}`. Thanks.

Comment: I know it's late but I have a quick question. Is render() called every time then? I thought it's just called once at the very beginning. I'm just curious how this method works

Comment: @KyleRichardson What if there are multiple Api calls needed to be done and needed to wait until all of them are loaded?

Answer (score 3):

```
constructor() {
  super()
  this.state = { isLoading: true }
}

componentDidMount() {
  ('fetch data').then(() => { this.setState({ isLoading: false }); })
}

render() {
  return (
    <div>
      {!this.state.isLoading && ('your code')}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Something like that.

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the state with empty data before fetching, in `constructor` like this

```
constructor(){
 ....,
 this.state = { house: null}
}
```

And put a condition in `getSlots` method which checks if data is fetched or not

```
getSlots (viewing) {

    if (!this.state.house) {
       return [];
    }

    SOME STUFF...

    const monday = this.state.house.monday

    return SOME STUFF...
  }
```

When the data arrives, then simply set the corresponding state like this

```
componentDidMount(){
   fetch().then((houses) => {
      this.setState({ houses: houses })
   })
}
```