# I can't access the object what I want from Poke API

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I cant access the object what I want. Some kinda object exist in this API. First I try to access poke name it's the easy one!

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import "./App.css";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

function PokemonList() {
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchPokemon();

  }, []); // square bracket means this only gone run when the component mounts

  const [pokemon, setPokemon] = useState([]);

  const fetchPokemon = async () => {
    const data = await fetch(`https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/3/`);
    const pokemon = await data.json();
    console.log(pokemon);
    setPokemon(pokemon);
```

I fetch the data inside of `pokemon` variable and then

```
return(
 <h1> {pokemon.name} </h1>
)
```

Success!

Now try to add types

[image]

this is the content from `pokemon object`

```
 <div>
        {pokemon.types.map(type => {
             return <h1>{type.type.name}</h1>
          })} 
      </div>
```

I write that code but not working.
I see that error message

[image]

So I can't react that infos.

By the way, I want to put the images on the screen.
[image]

It's kinda different from the types object (I just mention that in the first pic) `sprites` object doesn't exist like `0`, `1` nest object. We can directly see `back_default`(A nested object under sprites object) So that's examples, are that the same thing or is that really different example between that.

I am started the learn js, react. I hope you will help me, guys. I am stuck help me in that hole! pls :(

---

Btw, I found some usages for this API.

[image]

video link (time 33:44) = https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HaEB0vdxpdg

Why he uses in the first mention `map` function and use the `[0]` that thing (I don't understand what does it meant) in the second mention. Pls explanation.

---

## Update

When I add the empty object variable it's worked. -Thanks @AntoineFrau-

But When I deleted the nested items the project is still working. I was thought, It will break and stop working but It's working both of those ways. What is the explanation about this situation?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is it due to the fact that you're trying to access the `type.type.name`, but while you remove the nested objects they will be `undefined`. That's was the point of having the empty object of everything !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's caused by the fact that, React will render your component even if `pokemon` is `undefined`. So if you try to use `map()` function of an `undefined` variable it will crash.

One solution will be to initialized your Pokemon variable with a default object:

```
const [pokemon, setPokemon] = useState({
  "height": 0,
  "id": 0,
  "name": "",
  "sprites": {
    "default": ""
  }
  "types": [
    {
      "slot": 0,
      "type": {
        "name": "",
        "url": ""
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

```
<div>
   {
      pokemon.types.map(type => {
         return <h1>{type.type.name}</h1>
      })
   } 
</div>
```

Like that it will print nothing instead of crash.

PS: He use in the video `pokemon.abilities[0]` cause I guess he just want to show the first ability of the Pokemon.

## UPDATE

If you want you could also create a variable, which will block the render of your component if the data hasn't been loaded yet : https://stackoverflow.com/a/47850151/6809926

Comment: https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/3/ Look at those all parameter I have to add alls empty versions on the  inside of it. 
```const [pokemon, setPokemon] = useState({ });```

Comment: Yes I know, but you only can put the useful ones ?

Comment: And btw what is that mean in the empty string `[ ]` inside of it `useState()`
`const [pokemon, setPokemon] = useState([]);`

Comment: Meaning that the default value for you pokemon state is an empty array : [ ]

Comment: @HasanTezcan Updated the answer to provide you another way to do it.