# Fetch and array of objects from a database and displaying it with react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I was trying to fetch an array of objects when I encounter this problem.  Sorry for my messy code, I'm a beginner.

```
export class App extends Component {
  state ={
    character:[]
  }
  componentDidMount(){

     fetch('https://swapi.dev/api/people/').then(data => data.json()).then(res =>{
     this.setState(() =>{
       const ar = res.results

       return {
         character: ar
       }
     })
    })


  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
         test

          {console.log(this.state.character[0])}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

That code works fine for me at first until I changed the console log to `{console.log(this.state.character[0].name)}` it says "cannot read property of an undefined" even though the first line displays the object perfectly

Comment: Because `fetch()` is **asynchronous**. The `character` array is empty until it completes and sets the new state

Comment: `state.character` is the empty array `[]` at the beginning, before the `componentDidMount` sets the state. Your `render()` function will need to deal with that initial state as well.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React: How to wait data before using "this.state.x" into a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47850047/react-how-to-wait-data-before-using-this-state-x-into-a-function)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fetch is `asynchronous` so you will take some time to get the result but before that your jsx is called already. So it is good to use conditional jsx. Please check the **complete example** as below where I shown all the name of character array under li element.

```
export class App extends React.Component {
    state = {
        character: []
    };

    componentDidMount() {

        fetch('https://swapi.dev/api/people/').then(data => data.json()).then(res => {
            this.setState(() => {
                const ar = res.results;

                return {
                    character: ar
                }
            })
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                test
                {
                    this.state.character && this.state.character.length && this.state.character.map((item, index) => {
                       return <li key={index}>{item.name}</li>
                    })
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: so i can use at least 1 of the statement and it'll be fine right? and also how does the `map` function works does it mean checking if the `(item, index)` equal to true?

Comment: hi, map is kind of loop where item is the each item from the list (for ex. list. map() ) and index is the index of each item in the list.

Comment: TYSM brother <3

Answer (score 1):

Your `App` component fetches the data in `componentDidMount` life cycle method which will execute after the first mount. `{console.log(this.state.character[0].name)}` shows error "cannot read property of `undefined` because when the component mounts for first time, the data is not available yet, which means `this.state.character` is still an empty array. So when try to access `this.state.character[0].name`, its like saying give me the value of `undefined.name` which will give you an error because `name` property does not exist on `undefined`. To fix this issue you can check if `character.length` in a conditional and then try to access `.name`.

Example

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
         test

          {this.state.character.length && <p>{this.state.character[0].name}</p>}
      </div>
    )
  }
```

Comment: you're great at explaining sir i couldn't understand most of answer i get from stack overflow mainly because i'm a beginner and my english is lacking but i understand you completely i ran the `console.log` again it showed that the first 2 lines of response was `undefined` TYSM <3

Comment: Are you still having issues? What response was `undefined`?

Answer (score -1):

So that will not work. Data is not there yet. There are bunch of ways to workaround it. Most simple one is to have object structure predefined in the state object, which is not very dynamic. Otherwise simple `.length + if + else` will do the job.